# JQuery change background color using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I have 2 buttons one which should change background color to yellow, other one to red, however for some reason it seems not to work, no error in console but still no result:

HTML:

```
    <button class="btn btn-default form-control margin" value="yellow" class="color">Background</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default form-control margin" value="red" class="color">Background</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
        $('.color').click(function(){
        $('#content-link2 > #content').css({"background-color": ($(this).attr("value"))
        });
   });
});
```

Rest of HTML:

```
<div id="content-link2"></div>
```

And inside that div another html page is injected which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
        <link href="http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"/>
    </div>
<div  contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh"><p>hlo</p></div>
<div id="comments">
<form name="forma">
<textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" class="refresh" cols="40" rows="5">
Comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" id="send-data" /><!--onClick="writeComment(e);"--> 
<div id ="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
<p>This text can be by the user.</p>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share complete html

Comment: You have syntax error `$('#content').css({"background-color": $(this).attr("value") })`

Comment: try `$('#content')`

Comment: Job #1 when debugging JS: check the console for errors. In this case your `css()` syntax is wrong. http://api.jquery.com/css. Closing as a typo.

Comment: Ok so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : (add only one class attribute to each tag)

```
<button class="btn btn-default form-control margin color" value="yellow">Background</button>
<button class="btn btn-default form-control margin color" value="red">Background</button>
```

Then :

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    $('.color').click(function(){
    $('#content').css("background-color",$(this).attr("value"))
    });
  });
```

Comment: `color` Specifies the text color will not affect background color. the correct property is `background-color`

Comment: Works brilliant! wow i am really greatful issue was that I had 2 class attributes

Comment: happy to solve your problem. please check the green button that others can understand. goodluck @Przemek Wojtas